# Logcat does not show Logs of Galaxy Note3

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

`Logcat` does not show my App's `Logs`, but shows the system `Logs`. I am testing my Apps on Galaxy Note3 and its driver is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable USB Debugging on your device. Go to settings, applications, development and tick "USB Debugging". Then when your device is connected by USB you can see its name in DDMS as if it was another emulator or When using Eclipse, in the DDMS perspective, make sure the correct device (propably emulator-xxxx) is selected and highlighted. Only then will you get the logcat output in the logcat view.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but all what you have stated, i tried it. though, logcat does not show my logs

Comment: Make sure you imported the Log object and you use a syntax like `Log.v("tag", "some text");`

Comment: @DerGolem yes the object is used in the log statement, I even 2 days before saw the output but since today's morning it does not work at all. I restrted the system and eclipse but with no avail.

Comment: @DerGolem I do not think so, because the device is new i have it since one week. but now when i tried to run the app. i fot this message "Would you like ADT to automatically monitor logcat 
output for messages from applications in the workspace?" ther is two options,(1)NO,(2)yes monitor logcat blablabalbla...with priority higher than (Error,I,V,D,W,A)?

Comment: Try reinstalling the driver. Maybe something screwed it up... try starting adb in a console window and launch: `adb devices`[ENTER]. Just to see if your device is listed. Also when you launch your app, see if your device appears in the device list.

Comment: yes it it in the device list, but would you mind tellin me which option should i choose"please refer to my comment, the one before this one"